# Is this the correct way of using bools

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia

This is it:

```
 %hook SBUIController 
   -    (BOOL)shouldShowNotificationCentreTabControlOnFirstSwipe {

return FALSE;

}
%end
```

Nothing happens once compiled

Comment: Can you provide more details/context, please?

Comment: I'm trying to create a tweak and once it compiles, nothing happens!

Comment: You have not formatted your code well, you have not included a language tag, and you have included some tags which may not be relevant.

Comment: You can't just hook some random method and expect it to work like you want. Those aren't public APIs, those are internal classes. They can and do have many methods that have misleading names, crash when you do something wrong with them, don't work at all because nothing is calling them. That's a normal thing with reverse engineering and only thing you can do is keep searching for another solution or just open the binary in something like IDA and find out exactly how the application works.

Comment: Hooks aside, if your questions is "is this the correct way to use a bool", then the answer is "no". Or more specifically, you want `NO`, not `FALSE`.